# What this graph called and what is its equation?

Tags: graphing-functions

I am not a mathematician and the last time I used a formula complexer than sin(x) was during my university time about 10 years ago.

Recently I saw an interesting  graph but I couldn't find its formula or even its name.

here is an almost representation of [the graph](http://24.media.tumblr.com/0a2a333a3e23290f62d3e23346a261f2/tumblr_mlbsnhRMNK1s9lnrbo1_1280.png).

every time the graph descends, it descends to the top of last peak (in y value).

**I like to know**

- Is this graph has a name?
- What is its equation?

Comment: $\sin x + x$ would be close.

Comment: @AlexBecker, Thanks for the answer, it is close, but it does not descend to top top of last peak [here](https://www.google.com.my/search?q=sin(x)%2Bx&oq=sin(x)%2Bx)  it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this does the trick:
$$f(x) = \frac{2}{3 \pi} x + \cos{x}$$

It doesn't have any special names I'm aware of, though.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the answer I was looking for. You mathematicians have an amazing world! Google has a facility to see your graph here is the [link](https://www.google.com.my/search?q=2%2F%283*pi%29*x%2Bcos%28x%29)